# how to exclude ruleset in POM.XML?

Tags: java, maven, pmd, automation-testing

iam doing class project using maven plugin and pmd to check our code smell, i have to modify the ruselset since stuff like stdCyclomatic is deprecated but i don't know how, all other example i saw on the internet all have un-satisfying answer, can anyone tell me how to exclude stdCyclomatic from the rule set with POM.xml like this. Please dont suggest deleting the POM.xml, here is the ruleset segment of the pom.xml

```
    <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>/category/java/bestpractices.xml</ruleset>
                    <ruleset>/category/java/design.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <format>net.sourceforge.pmd.renderers.SummaryHTMLRenderer</format>
```

i expect i can exclude the stdCyclomatic from my ruleset so it wont show up anymore on the html report, i have try looking for example but there are none

Comment: Do not post images ... post text instead...

Comment: ok, i have edited the post

Comment: Without the full pom file etc. it's impossible to even guess whats really the problem..

Answer (score -1):

After some searching, i decided to create a pmd-exclude.xml file and write the inside similiar to this
https://github.com/IHTSDO/drugMatch/blob/master/src/main/resource/pmd-exclude.xml

then just add the pmd-exclude.xml to the ruleset section in pom.xml using this format

```
<rulesets>
                    <ruleset>pmd-exclude.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
```